# Calculating replenishment point - Set based SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2012

I have a view containing the following data, which represents a kind of schedule for 2 production cells. Each cell produces products consisting of several parts. Each production cell can potentially produce any product, but the production cycle times will generally vary from one cell to another for a given product, since this cells have different configurations (tooling, equipment, manpower, etc).

Production is scheduled in lots. Each row represents a span of time during which a given part will be consumed on a given cell and for a given lot and product. For instance, lot 1 consists of 2000 pieces of product 1, which is scheduled to run on cell 1 with a cycle time of 0.35 minutes per piece. Product 1 will use parts 1, 2 and 3 in the following quantities respectively: 76, 26 and 2 (this is all captured in the first 3 rows below).

```
+------+---------+------------------+------------------+-------+--------+---------+------+-------------+-----------+
| Cell | Product |   EstStartDate   |    EstEndDate    | Cycle | LotNum | Pending | Part | Consumption | TotalCons |
+------+---------+------------------+------------------+-------+--------+---------+------+-------------+-----------+
|    1 |       1 | 2014-05-27 08:00 | 2014-05-27 19:40 | 0.35  |      1 |    2000 |    1 |          76 |    152000 |
|    1 |       1 | 2014-05-27 08:00 | 2014-05-27 19:40 | 0.35  |      1 |    2000 |    2 |          26 |     52000 |
|    1 |       1 | 2014-05-27 08:00 | 2014-05-27 19:40 | 0.35  |      1 |    2000 |    3 |           2 |      4000 |
|    2 |       2 | 2014-05-27 08:00 | 2014-05-28 04:24 | 0.68  |      2 |    1800 |    1 |          55 |     99000 |
|    2 |       2 | 2014-05-27 08:00 | 2014-05-28 04:24 | 0.68  |      2 |    1800 |    3 |          12 |     21600 |
|    2 |       2 | 2014-05-27 08:00 | 2014-05-28 04:24 | 0.68  |      2 |    1800 |    4 |          16 |     28800 |
|    2 |       2 | 2014-05-27 08:00 | 2014-05-28 04:24 | 0.68  |      2 |    1800 |    5 |           1 |      1800 |
|    1 |       3 | 2014-05-27 19:40 | 2014-05-28 04:54 | 0.47  |      3 |    1200 |    2 |          38 |     45600 |
|    1 |       3 | 2014-05-27 19:40 | 2014-05-28 04:54 | 0.47  |      3 |    1200 |    4 |          21 |     25200 |
|    2 |       1 | 2014-05-28 04:24 | 2014-05-28 10:49 | 0.35  |      4 |    1100 |    1 |          76 |     83600 |
|    2 |       1 | 2014-05-28 04:24 | 2014-05-28 10:49 | 0.35  |      4 |    1100 |    2 |          26 |     28600 |
|    2 |       1 | 2014-05-28 04:24 | 2014-05-28 10:49 | 0.35  |      4 |    1100 |    3 |           2 |      2200 |
+------+---------+------------------+------------------+-------+--------+---------+------+-------------+-----------+
```

I also have a table showing the stock on hand in our warehouse. Each row represents a container (box) of parts. This boxes should be consumed FIFO (this is ordering by container id). What I would like to do is calculate which cell will consume which container and at what time.

```
+-----------+------+----------+------+--------------+------------+
| Container | Part | Quantity | Cell | EstStartDate | EstEndDate |
+-----------+------+----------+------+--------------+------------+
|         1 |    1 |    30000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|         2 |    1 |    30000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|         3 |    1 |    30000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|         4 |    1 |    30000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|         5 |    1 |    30000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|         6 |    1 |    10000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|         7 |    1 |    10000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|         8 |    1 |    10000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|         9 |    1 |    10000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        10 |    1 |    30000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        11 |    1 |    30000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        12 |    1 |    30000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        13 |    2 |    50000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        14 |    2 |    25000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        15 |    2 |    10000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        16 |    2 |    25000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        17 |    2 |    25000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        18 |    3 |    10000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        19 |    3 |    10000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        20 |    3 |    10000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        21 |    4 |    20000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        22 |    4 |    20000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        23 |    4 |    20000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
|        24 |    5 |    10000 | ??   | ??????       | ??????     |
+-----------+------+----------+------+--------------+------------+
```

I've been burning my brain with this, playing around with window functions and running totals. I know I can do this using cursors, but maybe it's possible to do it with a set based query also.

Can anyone help with this? I'm using SQL Server 2012.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that given the interactions involved in this problem (it sounds like a dynamic programming problem) you'll need to solve it procedurally (e.g. with cursors like you mention)

Comment: Yes that's the same thing I'm thinking. I'm trying to find out if this can be done using a different mind set (for instance one idea that is hovering my mind is to split the schedule a 5 minutes intervals and calculating the individual consumption for each part in that interval. Once I have that view maybe something can be done).

Comment: I started thinking of something similar but at some point you need to allocate a particular container to a particular cell and remember it. I believe that this will need to be done procedurally as the containers may contain different quantities of parts.