# Using plpy classes from outside PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql

I'm new to PostgreSQL and Python.

I'm migrating a project from MS SQL Server and .NET, and I'm having difficulties with a fairly complex stored procedure.

So far I've made it compile ("CREATE FUNCTION ..... LANGUAGE plpython3u" executes without errors), but when I try to run it I get runtime errors.

I googled about PL Python debugging and it seems there's not an easy way to do it.

So I think I can easily move most parts of the procedure to a function that will take some plpy result objects as arguments and then return another plpy result when done. This would not only allow me to run and debug the function outside PostgreSQL, but also maybe unit test it independently of the database.

My specific question is: can I create plpy result objects by hand outside PostgreSQL? Or maybe use another type of object that will behave exactly as a plpy result object?

Thanks in advance for any help on this.

Best regards,
Awer

Comment: There are [some utility functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/plpython-util.html) to debug plpython, but unless you have a good reason to write your stored procedures in python, I suggest you to use `plpgsql` and/or `sql` functions; those are usually easier to write and maintain (no extension needed).

Comment: I'm already using those utility functions, but it's very tedious to debug using only those.

Comment: I think I do need PL Python. This is what the procedure is doing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064689/calculating-replenishment-point-set-based-sql-query