# Map replenishment to requirement based on field value - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-order-by

I am attempting to find which "replenishment" (a positive transaction quantity) can be matched to a "requirement" (a negative transaction quantity).

The basic logic would be: For a given requirement, find the first available replenishment (whether that replenishment be from existing inventory, or from an upcoming change).

I am working with a table `dbo_purchases_new` that looks like this:

```
| Element_ID |   Element  | Transaction_Date | Transaction_Quantity | Total_Inventory |
|:----------:|:----------:|:----------------:|:--------------------:|:---------------:|
|            |    STOCK   |                  |           5          |        5        |
|    MO302   | Make_Order |     1/3/2019     |           1          |        6        |
|    SO105   |    Sale    |     2/1/2019     |          -1          |        5        |
|    SO106   |    Sale    |     2/1/2019     |          -1          |        4        |
|    MO323   | Make_Order |     2/2/2019     |           1          |        5        |
|    SO107   |    Sale    |     2/4/2019     |          -1          |        4        |
|    SO191   |    Sale    |     2/5/2019     |          -1          |        3        |
|    SO123   |    Sale    |     2/6/2019     |          -1          |        2        |
|    SO166   |    Sale    |     3/1/2019     |          -1          |        1        |
|    SO819   |    Sale    |     3/5/2019     |          -1          |        0        |
|    SO603   |    Sale    |     3/10/2019    |          -4          |        -3       |
|    MO400   | Make_Order |     3/15/2019    |           1          |        -2       |
|    MO459   | Make_Order |     3/15/2019    |           1          |        -1       |
|    MO460   | Make_Order |     3/18/2019    |           1          |        0        |
|    MO491   | Make_Order |     3/19/2019    |           1          |        1        |
|    MO715   | Make_Order |     4/1/2019     |           3          |        4        |
|    SO100   |    Sale    |     4/2/2019     |          -1          |        3        |
|    SO322   |    Sale    |     4/3/2019     |          -1          |        2        |
|    SO874   |    Sale    |     4/4/2019     |          -1          |        1        |
|    SO222   |    Sale    |     4/5/2019     |          -1          |        0        |
|    MO999   | Make_Order |     4/5/2019     |           1          |        1        |
|    SO999   |    Sale    |     4/6/2019     |          -1          |        0        |
```

that is being created as a result of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56532303/create-calculated-field-based-on-previous-rows-oracle-sql/56533675?noredirect=1#comment99678109_56533675).

I am now attempting to track which `Make_Order` will fulfill which `Sale` by tracking the `Transaction_Quantity`.

Ideally, the resulting dataset would look like this, where Replenishment and Replenishment_Date are newly added columns:

```
| Element_ID |   Element  | Transaction_Date | Transaction_Quantity | Total_Inventory | Replenishment | Replenishment_Date |
|:----------:|:----------:|:----------------:|:--------------------:|:---------------:|:-------------:|:------------------:|
|            |    STOCK   |                  |           5          |        5        |      NULL     |        NULL        |
|    MO302   | Make_Order |     1/3/2019     |           1          |        6        |      NULL     |        NULL        |
|    SO105   |    Sale    |     2/1/2019     |          -1          |        5        |     STOCK     |        NULL        |
|    SO106   |    Sale    |     2/1/2019     |          -1          |        4        |     STOCK     |        NULL        |
|    MO323   | Make_Order |     2/2/2019     |           1          |        5        |      NULL     |        NULL        |
|    SO107   |    Sale    |     2/4/2019     |          -1          |        4        |     STOCK     |        NULL        |
|    SO191   |    Sale    |     2/5/2019     |          -1          |        3        |     STOCK     |        NULL        |
|    SO123   |    Sale    |     2/6/2019     |          -1          |        2        |     STOCK     |        NULL        |
|    SO166   |    Sale    |     3/1/2019     |          -1          |        1        |     MO302     |      1/3/2019      |
|    SO819   |    Sale    |     3/5/2019     |          -1          |        0        |     MO323     |      2/2/2019      |
|    SO603   |    Sale    |     3/10/2019    |          -4          |        -3       |     MO460     |      3/18/2019     |
|    MO400   | Make_Order |     3/15/2019    |           1          |        -2       |      NULL     |        NULL        |
|    MO459   | Make_Order |     3/15/2019    |           1          |        -1       |      NULL     |                    |
|    MO460   | Make_Order |     3/18/2019    |           1          |        0        |      NULL     |        NULL        |
|    MO491   | Make_Order |     3/19/2019    |           1          |        1        |      NULL     |        NULL        |
|    MO715   | Make_Order |     4/1/2019     |           3          |        4        |      NULL     |        NULL        |
|    SO100   |    Sale    |     4/2/2019     |          -1          |        3        |     MO491     |      3/19/2019     |
|    SO322   |    Sale    |     4/3/2019     |          -1          |        2        |     MO715     |      4/1/2019      |
|    SO874   |    Sale    |     4/4/2019     |          -1          |        1        |     MO715     |      4/1/2019      |
|    SO222   |    Sale    |     4/5/2019     |          -1          |        0        |     MO715     |      4/1/2019      |
|    MO999   | Make_Order |     4/5/2019     |           1          |        1        |      NULL     |        NULL        |
|    SO999   |    Sale    |     4/6/2019     |          -1          |        0        |     SO999     |      4/5/2019      |
```

The ruleset would essentially be:
For a given requirement (a negative transaction quantity of arbitrary value), find which replenishment (a positive transaction quantity of arbitrary value) satisfies it.

1. Stock is assigned to the first requirements until it runs out. NOTE
   -- it could be the case that stock does not exist, so this only applies IF stock does exist
2. Then, map replenishments to requirements based on the
   Transaction_Date in ASC order

I am very confused on how to accomplish this. I imagine some pseudocode would look something like:

```
for curr in transaction_quantity:
    if curr < 0:
        if stock.exists() and stock.notempty():
          fill in data from that
        else:
            find next replenishment
            fill in data from that
    else:
        next
```

Right now, I have this so far, but I know that it will not run. I am very confused on where to go from here. I have tried looking at posts [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24064689/calculating-replenishment-point-set-based-sql-query), but that did not have an answer. I then [tried looking up](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1599/sql-server-cursor-example/) `CURSOR`, but that was very confusing to me and I am unsure how I can apply that to this problem.

```
/****** WiP Script  ******/
SELECT 
    [jerry].[dbo].[purchases_new].*,
    CASE WHEN Transaction_Quantity < 0 THEN -- (SELECT Element_ID FROM the_current_row WHERE transaction_quantity > 0)
    ELSE NULL AS "Replenishment",
    -- (SELECT Transaction_Date FROM [jerry].[dbo].[purchases_new] WHERE Element_ID 
    -- Not sure how to grab the correct date of the element id from the column before
FROM 
    [jerry].[dbo].[purchases_new]
```

Any assistance is appreciated. I have been pulling my hair out on this problem. The comments contain additional information.
NOTE - I have continually tried to update this question as users have requested more information.

Comment: `Transaction_Quantity < 0 THEN `, then what?  From you description, it appears you may want to join back to the same table perhaps?

Comment: That's what I have commented out, because I'm not sure how to write the `SQL`, which is the basis of my question. If the `Transaction_Quantity` is negative, find the "Replenishment" that satisfies that, i.e., the "first" positive value. I have posted an example of what I am trying to accomplish that I did manually by hand, but I don't know how to translate that to code.

Comment: If you have two "make order" on the same date, which one "wins", i.e. what order?
If you have multiple "make order" and "sale" on the same date, how is that to be handled? (orders first, sales first, something random etc?)

Comment: In the event that two positive quantities (`make_order`) appear on the same day, it frankly does not matter which is selected. The lowest level of granularity we care about is day, so that should be fine. 

If there are multiple `make_order` and `sale` on the same day, I'm not sure I follow your question. Each sale (negative quantity change) would need to be satisfied by a positive quantity change, and the first available would need to be selected. If that fell on the same day, then that is what would need to be selected.

Comment: Do you really need to track makeorders against immediate fulfillment from inventory? I can understand wanting to track for line items where a fulfillment is the gate (backorder), but the former doesn't seem necessary. And if it is not, you might make this easier with a function.

Comment: I think you're chasing a ghost. Say you get one unit in on Monday and another on Tuesday. On Wednesday you make a sale for four units. On Friday, two additional units come in to fulfill the sale. Which purchase order fulfilled the sale?

Comment: @DrDoomPDX unfortunately, the answer is yes. Even if the current inventory is 10000, I would need to know which one of the positive transaction quantities that contributed to that inventory could satisfy a sale. Trying to make this 1:1. And if I can do that with a function, that'd be great. I didn't even know you could do that in SQL.

Comment: @EricBrandt Friday, since the other two still yielded you a "negative" amount.

Comment: What about split fulfillment? Would an order of 500 be the record for fulfillment until the 500 meets zero? This could get quite complicated and not likely resolvable with a single query. Might need a proc that creates some temp data and runs updates. I am putting my head into it a little bit. Are there any limiters we should know about?

Comment: I'm willing to work with you to create an answer for this, as there is at least one other question on SO that has not been answered regarding the same issue, and I'd imagine more. But to answer that question, yes, it would be that record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one attempt. You will need to modify if with another layer of abstraction for offsets if you need to support transaction increments/decrements > 1. It basically aligns the order of sales with the order of debits and then uses that as join back to the main dataset.

[Sql Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ce405/1)

The idea is to put additions and subtractions into two sets, orderd chronologically by set, while also remembering order of each item back into the main list. This way, you can align each subtraction with the nearest addition. This is pretty straightforward when dealing with 1's.

Edit --> Dealing with values > 1.

Computing `Transaction_Amount` > (+/-)1 adds a little complexity, but still solvable. Now we need to stretch each addition and subtraction transaction set out by the Transaction_Amount, so the dataset is lengthened, however, the original algorithm will still be applied to a now longer dataset. This will allow for the recording of "partial fulfillments". So  `(12 A 5)` would equate to `(12 A 1), (12 A 1), (12 A 1), (12 A 1), (12 A 1)`. Now, when the subtractors are lengthened in similar fashion, (with all rows in the same order as the first of the sequence) the alignment will still work and addition and subtractions can be matched with the nearest neighbor(s).

```
DECLARE @T TABLE(Element_ID NVARCHAR(50),Element NVARCHAR(50), Transaction_Date DATETIME,Transaction_Quantity INT,Total_Inventory INT)
INSERT @T VALUES
('MO301','Make_Order','1/1/2019',5,1),
('MO302','Make_Order','1/3/2019',1,2),
('SO105','Sale','2/1/2019',-2,1),
('SO106','Sale','2/1/2019',-1,0),
('MO323','Make_Order','2/2/2019',1,1),
('SO107','Sale','2/4/2019',-1,0),
('SO191','Sale','2/5/2019',-1,-1),
('SO123','Sale','2/6/2019',-1,-2),
('SO166','Sale','3/1/2019',-1,-3),
('SO603','Sale','3/2/2019',-1,-4),
('MO400','Make_Order','3/15/2019',1,-3),
('MO459','Make_Order','3/15/2019',1,-2),
('MO460','Make_Order','3/18/2019',1,-1),
('MO491','Make_Order','3/19/2019',1,0)


;WITH Normalized AS
(
    SELECT *, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)), IsAdd = CASE WHEN Transaction_Quantity>0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END FROM @T
)

,ReplicateAmount AS
 (
    SELECT  Element_ID, Element, Transaction_Date, Transaction_Quantity=ABS(Transaction_Quantity) ,Total_Inventory, RowNumber, IsAdd
    FROM Normalized

    UNION ALL

    SELECT R.Element_ID, R.Element, R.Transaction_Date, Transaction_Quantity=(R.Transaction_Quantity - 1), R.Total_Inventory, R.RowNumber, R.IsAdd
    FROM ReplicateAmount R INNER JOIN Normalized N ON R.RowNumber = N.RowNumber
    WHERE ABS(R.Transaction_Quantity) > 1
)
,NormalizedAgain AS
(
    SELECT Element_ID, Element, Transaction_Date, Transaction_Quantity=1, Total_Inventory, RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowNumber), IsAdd FROM ReplicateAmount
)
,Additives AS
(
    SELECT *, AddedOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) FROM NormalizedAgain WHERE  IsAdd=1
)
,Subtractions AS
(
    SELECT Element_ID, Element, Transaction_Date, Transaction_Quantity=-1 , Total_Inventory, RowNumber,  SubtractedOrder = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))FROM NormalizedAgain  WHERE IsAdd=0
)
,WithTies AS
(
    SELECT 
        S.RowNumber,
        S.Element_ID,
        BoughtFromRowNumber = A.RowNumber,
        SoldToID =S.Element_ID,
        BoughFromID=A.Element_ID,
        S.Element,
        S.Transaction_Date,
        S.Transaction_Quantity,
        S.Total_Inventory
    FROM 
        Additives A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  Subtractions S ON A.AddedOrder=S.SubtractedOrder 

    UNION  

    SELECT 
        A.RowNumber,
        A.Element_ID,
        BoughtFromRowNumber = S.RowNumber,
        SoldToID = NULL,
        BoughFromID=NULL,
        A.Element,
        A.Transaction_Date,
        A.Transaction_Quantity,
        A.Total_Inventory
    FROM 
        Additives A
        LEFT OUTER JOIN  Subtractions S ON A.AddedOrder=S.SubtractedOrder 
)
SELECT 
    T.RowNumber,
    T.Element_ID,
    T.Element,
    T.Transaction_Date,
    T.Transaction_Quantity,
    T.Total_Inventory,
    T2.SoldToID,
    T.BoughFromID
FROM 
    WithTies T
    LEFT OUTER JOIN WithTies T2 ON T2.BoughtFromRowNumber= T.RowNumber  
WHERE
    NOT T.RowNumber IS NULL
ORDER BY 
    T.RowNumber
```

Comment: This looks really good! Thank you very much. I am trying to add in that "layer of abstraction" you mention and I'm seemingly unable. Are you able to possibly edit your answer to do so, for values that may be `> 1`

Comment: Layer added, and it lengthens the dataset, however, it may be unavoidable...still looking for a more performant solution.